# Substituir arquivos com sed

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

Olá, tenho um problema que preciso resolver. Possuo um arquivo que deve ser inserido exatamente um uma coluna de outro arquivo, estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
cat $1 | cut -d ',' -f2 | tr "/" "-" | awk -F "-" '{print $2"-"$1"-"$3}' > temp.txt
```

`cat $1 | sed 's/[0-3][0-9]\/[0-1][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/temp.txt/'`

Do qual temp.txt é o arquivo que possui a coluna atualizada. O problema é que em vez de substituir a coluna especificada, ele esta substituindo pelo nome do arquivo "temp.txt". 
Alguma sugestão para arrumar isto? Ou outra forma de se fazer? Obrigado!

Comment: Pode explicar melhor? Não entendi bem o seu problema.

Comment: o meu problema é o seguinte: Alterar para que a coluna seja "Ano-Mês-Dia"
Exemplo: converter de 22/12/2012 para 2012-12-22

Comment: Edite a pergunta....

Comment: Eu gerei um arquivo com a alteração chamado tempo.txt, no formato 12-22-2012. Preciso inserir este arquivo na segunda coluna de outro arquivo .csv

Answer (score 2):

Apesar da pergunta estar muito estranha (dica para o futuro, indica o que queres fazer e não o que estas a fazer, pois podes estar a seguir o caminho errado), presumo que queiras trocar o campo data do formato US (que é totalmente ilógico, mas eles são assim). mês/dia/ano, para dia-mês-ano.

Nesse caso, bastará isto:

```
cat $1 | sed -r 's,([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4}),\2-\1-\3,g'
```

as "," estão a substituir as "/" usuais no sed, para evitar escapar os "/" e o -r para usar regexp estendida

Comment: cool (+1) . eventualmente eliminar o cat: `sed -r 's.......' $1`

Answer (score 1):

A solução proposta pelo @higuita é perfeita (resolve o problema de uma vez só).

No entanto respondendo diretamente à tua sub-pergunta : *meter ficheiro na coluna 2 de um ficheiro csv*, podes usar o comando **paste**:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1 a.csv ) coluna2.txt <(cut -d, -f3- a.csv)
```

- `paste` - junta lado a lado
- `-d,`  - separador de colunas `,`
- `<(cut -d, -f1 a.csv )` - extrai a coluna 1 do ficheiro a.csv
- `<(cut -d, -f3- a.csv)` - extrai as colunas 3 em diante